# Android FragmentTransaction Replace method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem passing arguments down to the fragment from my main activity. getArguments method returns null but at the same time the fragment displays the arguments I'm trying to pass but in a different position. I'm sure it has to do with the container I'm replacing on the replace method.

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment_tag";
    public static final String USER_NAME = "userName";
    public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "userPassword";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        User user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(LoginActivityFragment.SERVER_MESSAGE);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(USER_NAME, user.getUser_name());
        bundle.putString(USER_PASSWORD, user.getUser_password());

        if (user != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            MainActivityFragment fragment = (MainActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if (fragment != null) {
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            } else {
                MainActivityFragment newFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My MainActivityFragment:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String ERROR = "Error";

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView username = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username_test);
        TextView password = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pass_test);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        try {
            username.setText(bundle.getString(MainActivity.USER_NAME));
            password.setText(bundle.getString(MainActivity.USER_PASSWORD));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(ERROR, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.msc.ebla.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </SearchView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main Layout

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.msc.ebla.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

MainActivityFragment Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.msc.ebla.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="user"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pass"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot of the emulator when I'm passing testName and testPass as arguments:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are loading two `Fragment`s - one static, one dynamic. The static `Fragment` you declare in `xml`, and in this one `getArguments()` will always return `null`. The dynamic `Fragment` however should not.

I'd suggest you only use dynamic fragments. Replace:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.msc.ebla.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

With

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

And in your `MainActivity`, replace any reference to `android.R.id.content` with `R.id.fragment_container`

**Edit:**

By the way, I'd recommend using the `newInstance()` method to pass arguments to your `Fragment`s as it's more reliable. Add this method declaration to `MainActivityFragment`:

```
public static MainActivityFragment newInstance(String userName, String userPassword) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(USER_NAME_KEY, userName);
    args.putString(USER_PASSWORD_KEY, userPassword);

    MainActivityFragment frag = new MainActivityFragment();
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;

}
```

And instead of using `new MainActivityFragment()` to create a new instance, use `MainActivityFragment.newInstance("user_name", "user_password)`. There's a bit more info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

### For "getArgument()" return null issue:

You should set argument **BEFORE** calling replace() and commit(). So, change the code to something like this:

```
MainActivityFragment newFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
ft.commit();
```

---

### For Layout Issue :

Your content_main Layout is on the same level as AppBar layout. You have to put it **inside AppBar layout.**Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

      <SearchView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      </SearchView>



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```